# Ant build works on one system and not another

Tags: java, ant, compiler-errors, hudson, findbugs

We recently added FindBugs to our build and test process, but we've run into problems building when we are using the @SuppressWarning annotation.

More interestingly, the code will compile on our three developer laptops, but not on our build system, even though the code is the same and the Java compiler in use is the same (1.5.0_22 - 32 bit).

Here is the problem:  We have a project, HCSBeans, that depends on another project, CommonLibrary.  CommonLibrary uses @SuppressWarning once, while HCSBeans does not.  CommonLibrary builds on our laptops and the build system, but HCSBeans does not build on the build system.  At this point I cannot find a difference between the build system and my laptop.

Here is the verbose Ant output from the build system (note: we are not using Maven):

```
-do-compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\build\empty
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\BindingHandler.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\BindingHandler.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\JRadioButtonUpdatable.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\JRadioButtonUpdatable.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\JTextAreaSizeFix.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\JTextAreaSizeFix.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCAssignmentPanel.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCAssignmentPanel.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCCheckBox.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCCheckBox.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCLabel.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCLabel.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCLabelBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCLabelBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCPanel.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCPanel.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCPanelBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCPanelBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButton.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButton.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonGroup.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonGroup.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonGroupBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonGroupBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCScrollPane.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCScrollPane.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCScrollPaneBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCScrollPaneBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSeparator.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSeparator.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSeparatorBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSeparatorBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSplitPane.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSplitPane.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSplitPaneBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSplitPaneBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTabbedPane.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTabbedPane.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTabbedPaneBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTabbedPaneBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTable.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTable.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTableBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTableBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextArea.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextArea.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextAreaBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextAreaBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextField.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextField.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextFieldBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextFieldBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextPane.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextPane.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextPaneBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextPaneBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\RoundButtonBorder.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\RoundButtonBorder.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\TextLabelUI.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\TextLabelUI.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\TextTransfer.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\TextTransfer.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\TouchButton.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\TouchButton.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\TouchButtonUpdatable.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\TouchButtonUpdatable.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\resources\black_box.gif skipped - don't know how to handle it
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\resources\black_box_disabled.gif skipped - don't know how to handle it
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\resources\black_box_x.gif skipped - don't know how to handle it
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\resources\black_box_x_disabled.gif skipped - don't know how to handle it
    [javac] Compiling 34 source files to C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\build\classes
    [javac] Using external javac compiler
    [javac] Compilation arguments:
    [javac] '-d'
    [javac] 'C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\build\classes'
    [javac] '-classpath'
    [javac] 'C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\build\classes;C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\CommonLibrary\dist\CommonLibrary.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\lib\swing-layout-1.0.4.jar'
    [javac] '-sourcepath'
    [javac] 'C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\build\empty'
    [javac] '-target'
    [javac] '1.5'
    [javac] '-encoding'
    [javac] 'windows-1252'
    [javac] '-g'
    [javac] '-source'
    [javac] '1.5'
    [javac]
    [javac] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
    [javac] not part of the command.
    [javac] Files to be compiled:
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\BindingHandler.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\JRadioButtonUpdatable.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\JTextAreaSizeFix.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCAssignmentPanel.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCCheckBox.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCLabel.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCLabelBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCPanel.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCPanelBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButton.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonGroup.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonGroupBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCScrollPane.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCScrollPaneBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSeparator.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSeparatorBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSplitPane.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSplitPaneBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTabbedPane.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTabbedPaneBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTable.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTableBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextArea.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextAreaBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextField.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextFieldBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextPane.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextPaneBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\RoundButtonBorder.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\TextLabelUI.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\TextTransfer.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\TouchButton.java
    [javac]     C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\TouchButtonUpdatable.java
    [javac] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.5.0_22). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
    [javac] com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: file edu\umd\cs\findbugs\annotations\SuppressWarnings.class not found
      [ant] Exiting C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\HCSBeans\build.xml.
  [antcall] Exiting C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\nb\build.xml.
```

Here is the verbose Ant output from my laptop:

```
-do-compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\build\empty
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\BindingHandler.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\BindingHandler.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\JRadioButtonUpdatable.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\JRadioButtonUpdatable.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\JTextAreaSizeFix.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\JTextAreaSizeFix.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCAssignmentPanel.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCAssignmentPanel.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCCheckBox.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCCheckBox.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCLabel.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCLabel.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCLabelBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCLabelBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCPanel.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCPanel.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCPanelBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCPanelBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButton.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButton.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonGroup.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonGroup.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonGroupBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonGroupBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCScrollPane.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCScrollPane.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCScrollPaneBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCScrollPaneBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSeparator.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSeparator.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSeparatorBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSeparatorBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSplitPane.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSplitPane.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSplitPaneBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSplitPaneBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTabbedPane.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTabbedPane.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTabbedPaneBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTabbedPaneBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTable.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTable.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTableBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTableBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextArea.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextArea.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextAreaBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextAreaBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextField.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextField.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextFieldBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextFieldBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextPane.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextPane.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextPaneBeanInfo.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextPaneBeanInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\RoundButtonBorder.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\RoundButtonBorder.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\TextLabelUI.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\TextLabelUI.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\TextTransfer.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\TextTransfer.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\TouchButton.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\TouchButton.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com\hcs\orc\ui\TouchButtonUpdatable.java added as com\hcs\orc\ui\TouchButtonUpdatable.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\resources\black_box.gif skipped - don't know how to handle it
    [javac] C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\resources\black_box_disabled.gif skipped - don't know how to handle it
    [javac] C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\resources\black_box_x.gif skipped - don't know how to handle it
    [javac] C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\resources\black_box_x_disabled.gif skipped - don't know how to handle it
    [javac] Compiling 34 source files to C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\build\classes
    [javac] Using external javac compiler
    [javac] Compilation arguments:
    [javac] '-d'
    [javac] 'C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\build\classes'
    [javac] '-classpath'
    [javac] 'C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\build\classes;C:\hcs\orc\nb\CommonLibrary\dist\CommonLibrary.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2\platform\modules\ext\swing-layout-1.0.4.jar'
    [javac] '-sourcepath'
    [javac] 'C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\build\empty'
    [javac] '-target'
    [javac] '1.5'
    [javac] '-encoding'
    [javac] 'windows-1252'
    [javac] '-g'
    [javac] '-source'
    [javac] '1.5'
    [javac]
    [javac] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
    [javac] not part of the command.
    [javac] Files to be compiled:
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\BindingHandler.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\JRadioButtonUpdatable.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\JTextAreaSizeFix.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCAssignmentPanel.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCCheckBox.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCLabel.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCLabelBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCPanel.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCPanelBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButton.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonGroup.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCRadioButtonGroupBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCScrollPane.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCScrollPaneBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSeparator.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSeparatorBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSplitPane.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCSplitPaneBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTabbedPane.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTabbedPaneBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTable.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTableBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextArea.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextAreaBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextField.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextFieldBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextPane.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\ORCTextPaneBeanInfo.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\RoundButtonBorder.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\TextLabelUI.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\TextTransfer.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\TouchButton.java
    [javac]     C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\src\com\hcs\orc\ui\TouchButtonUpdatable.java
```

Other than the compile error, I don't see any difference.

Other things worth noting:

1. Deleting and rechecking out the source code for both projects
   from SVN.
2. Comparing the versions of Java.  Both are 32-bit Java 1.5.0_22.  I know that is old, but we have customers who insist upon it.
3. There is only one reference to @SuppressWarning in CommonLibrary and none in HCSBeans.
4. We use annotations.jar and jsr305.jar when building the CommonLibrary, but they are not packaged with it and not referenced by HCSBeans.  They should not be necessary after the build.
5. Our laptops are 64-bit while the build system is 32-bit, but both Java installs are 32-bit.
6. All computers are MS Windows.

**Update**

I switched the build server to compile HCSBean with Java 1.6 and the code compiles (after removing an unused import to SwingUtilities2), but if I switch it back to Java 1.5 it still fails with the same error.  I'm beginning to suspect a problem with the Java 1.5 compiler.

**Update 2**

Well a co-worker found the actual difference.  Not sure why it is occurring, but here is the difference between the resulting builds.  On our laptops, the CommonLibrary.jar MANIFEST.MF file contains this line:

```
Class-Path: lib/annotations.jar lib/jsr305.jar
```

This means that building the HCSBeans project, it finds the annotations.jar file it needs.  However, this Class-Path line is not present when we build on the build server.  Not sure why, but that is the next line of investigation.

Comment: Is it possible to re-install java on the build machine (or install it again in a seperate location, I don't know if that is possible on Windows)? A compiler error is quite serious, so I'd have thought try that first.

Comment: on your developer laptops, are you running ant from within Netbeans, or from a standalone ant installation? If from within Netbeans, do you get the same error when running from standalone ant on the dev laptops?

Comment: Running it standalone and within Netbeans on the laptops.  Same results.

Comment: @Disco3 I installed JDK 1.5.0_u15 and got the same result.  Now I'm really puzzled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we found the problem.  Our laptops, having NetBeans installed (even if we weren't building directly from NetBeans) were using the CopyLibs to build the jar file, which added the needed line to the Manifest.MF file:

```
Class-Path: lib/annotations.jar lib/jsr305.jar
```

However, our build server, not having NetBeans installed was using j2seproject1:jar to build the jar file.

The solution was to add this to the -D Javac properties when building on our build server (which is Hudson, for those interested):

```
libs.CopyLibs.classpath=C:\\Documents and Settings\\stephen\\.hudson\\jobs\\ORC Trunk\\workspace\\orc\\lib\\netbeans\\org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
```

Now both our laptops and the build server are using CopyLibs and they both compile.

Yikes!  What a mess to figure out.

Thanks for those who gave me pointers along the way ( @Peter-Eliot & @Disco3 ).

Answer (score 0):

looks like the library is using the FindBugs version of SuppressWarning, not the `java.lang` version. `@SuppressWarning` to `@java.lang.SuppressWarning` and/or remove the import of the FindBugs version of SuppressWarning and see if that fixes it?

Also try adding FindBugs as a library in the classpath hudson looks at.  It looks like on your developer machines you are building in NetBeans, and I wouldn't be shocked if Netbeans snuck FindBugs into the classpath that ant uses

Comment: We reference \@SuppressWarnings as \@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings(...), so Java shouldn't get it confused between java.lang and edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.

Removing the FindBugs version of \@SuppressWarning may fix the compile problem, but renders FindBugs useless to us (too many Warnings that we'll be checking over and over again).

Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution where I can use FindBugs \@SuppressWarnings and compile.

Comment: added another possible solution -- it might be a classpath issue between Netbeans and Hudson

Comment: Both classpaths are shown in output above and look the same (minus the root directory) to me.  I should have stated that I'm running both Ants on the command line now (to remove the variables of Netbeans and Hudson).

Comment: is the ant output from the command line runs on the two machines exactly the same as the text pasted in the question? Specifically, is it still using `C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2\platform\modules\ext\swing-layout-1.0.4.jar'` on the dev laptop and `C:\Documents and Settings\stephen\.hudson\jobs\ORC Trunk\workspace\orc\lib\swing-layout-1.0.4.jar` on the Hudson box?

Comment: Peter, good catch.  I fixed that problem on the laptop so it matches the build system: `[javac] 'C:\hcs\orc\nb\HCSBeans\build\classes;C:\hcs\orc\nb\CommonLibrary\dist\CommonLibrary.jar;C:\hcs\orc\lib\swing-layout-1.0.4.jar'`, but that did not reproduce the failure on the laptop.

Comment: is `findbugs-ant.jar` in the lib directory of both ant installations?

Comment: It is in the lib directory and FindBugs Ant task works when you can compile correctly.

Comment: Using the separate `SuppressFBWarnings` annotation will avoid all confusion.